# $ f(x^*)=\sup_{x\in C}{\langle x^*,x\rangle} $ is $\sigma(X^*,X)$-lower semicontinuous.

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-topology

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $C\subset X$ be a nonempty, closed, and convex set.

Let $f:X^{*}\to \mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ defined by:
$$
f(x^*)=\sup_{x\in C}{\langle x^*,x\rangle}
$$

Show that : $f$ is $\sigma(X^*,X)$-lower semicontinuous.

An idea please.

Comment: What does $\sigma(X^*,X)$ denote?

Comment: @Renard lower semicontinuous from $X^*$ to $X$ with respect to the weak topology between them.

Answer (score 3):

for any $a\in \mathbb R$,
\begin{align}
\{x^*: f(x^*)\leq a\}&=\{x^*:\sup_{x\in C}\langle x, x^*\rangle\leq a\}\\
&=\bigcap_{x\in C}\{x^*:\langle x, x^*\rangle\leq a\}
\end{align}

Comment: then the hypothesis of $C$  is closed and convex is not necessary

Comment: But why : $\{x^*~:~\langle x,x^*\rangle\leq a\}$ is $\sigma(X^*,X)$-closed?

Comment: remember the definition of $\sigma(X^*, X)$.